# Is this the right way to send more than one NSMutableURLRequest Asynchronously?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

```
 __block   NSInteger outstandingRequests = [requestsArray count];
        for (NSURLRequest *request in requestsArray)
        {
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                               queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
                                    {
                                      [self parseData:data];

                                       outstandingRequests--;
                                       if (outstandingRequests == 0)
                                       {
                                           [delegate finishApproveRejectAll];
                                       }
                                   }];
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use NSOperationQueue if request is more than one at a time

Answer (score 0):

put this on .h

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)ASINetworkQueue *networkQueue;
```

set request

```
for (int i=0; i<[RequesttList count]; i++)
{
 ASIHTTPRequest *request=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
        request.tag = i;

        [[self networkQueue] addOperation:request];
}
```